# Is it possible some of a beta decay's energy goes into a strong recoil against the nucleus?

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, radiation

Reading about the 'history' of beta decays and neutrinos, I learned that some early-twentieth-century physicists and chemists thought that the 'missing energy' of beta decays didn't go into [Wolfgang Pauli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolfgang_Pauli)'s hypothesized 'neutrinos', but either just disappeared (violating conservation of energy) or resulted in an extra-strong recoil to the nucleus.

I know that Clyde Cowan discovered neutrinos a long time ago, but how sure are we that some nuclei don't receive an especially strong kick?

Would this result in 'spontaneous fission'?

Comment: Kurt Hikes: "_Reading about the 'history' of beta decays and neutrinos, I learned that some early-20th-century physicists and chemists thought that the 'missing energy' of beta decays [...] resulted in [...]_" -- Would you please share where specificly you read about this? (I've found it hard to research the "state of the art in radioactivity" before Pauli made his brilliant proposal ...) "_[...] an extra-strong recoil to the nucleus._" -- Some variant under active consideration: [Neutrinoless_double_beta_decay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_beta_decay#Neutrinoless_double_beta_decay).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but either just disappeared (violating conservation of energy) or resulted in an extra-strong recoil to the nucleus.

This would violate momentum conservation at the center of mass system. One has to work with [four vectors,](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/vec4.html) whose algebra  obeys the  the [conservation laws.](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/conser.html) Nuclear interactions were of the first evidence for a need of special relativity in interactions.

> how sure are we that some nuclei don't receive an especially strong kick?

The strength of a hit at the center of mass is contained in the energy and momentum conservation laws.